# Best practice example to design a moderate complicated data viz app in React with Redux

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, redux

All:

I am pretty new to React and Redux, what I am trying to build is a linechart (currently with D3.js).

The general UI structure of linechart is :

1. Main linechart area: several lines and X-Axis(date), Y-Axis(value),
2. Legend area: text label(with according color according to line)

I wonder could anyone give me **ANY example** with explaination how to implement this in React+Redux?

My currently confuse mainly is about two things:

1. How do I plan the container components and presentational components(from Redux tutorial, it seems that I need to build a lot of container components to wrap every presentational components which make things compilicated)
2. How to implement the initial start up of App(like what is the best way to do AJAX to get initial data and rendering, from Redux, it talks something like middleware, but I just can not get why and how to use that)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to keep it simple and add tools to your toolbox when you need the extra features and understand the implications.

1. I would advise you to only use React for now and try and see how far you can get without all the fancy React ecosystem features. It gets very frustrating if you don't have a clear understanding of how React works. Once you get familiar with React, you can look at Flux-like implementations like Redux and the problems they might solve for you.
2. If you choose this route, you can use your favorite ajax library (e.g. [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch)) to get remote data into your components. You can do this fetching using the different component lifecycles that React provides (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

Comment: Thanks, this seems like my Plan-B option, but I will definitely go this way if I still can not figure this out after every trying.